# okta deep link to page in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, okta

I'm using okta as my identity provider to get access to my aws accounts. I can get links to log in to the default console page with the different roles which I have set up.

I want to be able to create deep links to specific pages in the aws console. For example a deep link to a cloudwatch dashboard for a specific account and role. Anyone with the appropriate permissions in okta should be able to use this link to go directly to that page.

Is there an integration that provides this out of the box? Any docs that can help me set this up?

I initially thought this would be something super common and easy... All I have found is this blog post with expired links https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-saml-to-automatically-direct-federated-users-to-a-specific-aws-management-console-page/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put your AWS console URL as urlEncoded_RelayState in the following:

https://{{oktaDomain}}/sso/idps/{{idpId}}?fromURI={{urlEncoded_IDPLoginURL?RelayState={{urlEncoded_RelayState}}}}

https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/SSO-into-SAML-app-with-RelayState-via-OpenID-Connect-Identity-Provider?language=en_US